# How to store the string array into databse?

Tags: servlets, jdbc, oracle10g

```
In my java servlet application!
```

i am getting the checkbox selected values
as in the form of String[] by using the

```
String[] skills = request.getParameterValues("skills");
```

Now i have to store this string[] skillset values into oracle db!
I got 2 small solutions
1) i will take that string array into 1 string by appending (,) or (/).
   then i will store that in db (skill VARCHAR(1000))column.
   taking size like this in db column is not such a good practise.
2) I have a plan!
   I will take all checkbox names as columns in db like(C Boolean, C++ boolean, Java boolean.....).
then at the time of creating table i will make all their default value as false.
when the perticuler checkbox is checked then i will insert the value true as in db for example if user select checkbox java only then i will insert in db true as it's value.

"This seems very complex process"
from my perspective these 2 options are just tricky, but not an enterprise standard use!
Is there any way to store the String array in db other than like these stuppid tricks???

Is there any data type usage in db that takes our String[]
and gives back our string[] ??

if any?
please provide me with detailed steps!!

Thanks in advance!

### Recently i find one solution: VARRAY in oracle db =>

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE smoketype IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR(30)
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE register (fname VARCHAR(30), lname VARCHAR(30), gender VARCHAR
(1), smoke SMOKETYPE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO register VALUES
  2  (
  3  'omkar','t','m',
  4  smoketype('no')
  5  );

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO register VALUES
  2  (
  3  'om','T','m',
  4  smoketype('no','not at all')
  5  );

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO register VALUES
  2  (
  3  'onky','T','m',
  4  smoketype('no','never','not at all')
  5  );

1 row created.
```

with the above .. i created a type that takes multiple values just like an array.
but in my servlet when i create a statement and execute a selec * from register
query then i will get
the ResultSet obj!
but how could i retrieve that smoketype array into String[] back?
how could i retrieve the string[] values?
please someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is every value in the string array an actual string, or just a flag of some sort? true/false etc

If it's just a flag you can store it as a mask with each bit corresponding to some specific checkbox,

For example, if you have 3 checkboxes x,y,z with values true/false, you can have the mask be 3 bits, such as   101 (deonoting x = 1, y = 0, z = 1).

It's not the most descriptive way to store it as you have to keep track of actually your mask means, but it saves more space than just concatenating every value of you array